# The changes I do in back-end panel doesn't reflect in front-end.

Tags: admin, shipping, shipping-methods, delivery, flat

I am new to Magento. I am trying to configure a Magento Site that runs 1.8 version. I want to provide free shipping to customers only if the order value is above 300, else charge 30 per delivery. I tried configuring Flat Rate, Free shipping, and even tried to add a rule. But the changes are not reflected in front end. There is only one Shipping method called "Standard Shipping" that does not charge any amount for shipping. Could anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Whenever your site is under development always make  **Cache Storage Management** as disable or after making changes flush the cache to reflect the changes. To disable or clear the cache navigate to **System->Cache Management** then select all and flush Cache Storage.

If still your changes are not reflection then clear your /var/cache directory.

2) For fix 30 per delivery charges you can use Flat rate shipping method with following configuration.

[image]

3) For free shipping on order above 300 you need to create a shopping cart rule with following details.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank u so much. I have tried this. Its working fine but there comes a problem when you add or remove items in the cart. The shipping cost is not recalculating as per rule. It is recalculating only after clearing browser caches. Any Solution for this?

Comment: on which page you are checking cart or checkout?

Comment: Not recalculating in both cart and checkout pages

Comment: is your store is live or hosted on any test domain?

Comment: can you please provide me code and category on which i can test

Comment: can you pleas come for a chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40539/chat-with-xtech

Comment: You can try out on any category but don't place order

Comment: can't talk in chat since i don't have enough reputations

Comment: ok have u enable the shipping method and rule

Comment: Yes we have enabled.

Comment: ok. rule dont require code right ? and  can i make registration

Comment: Yes u can register but don't place order

Comment: yes i am not going to place order

Comment: have u made rule for login user only ?

Comment: no we have not added rule. only login user can place order

Comment: have u created a rule in admin for free shipping ?

Comment: yes we have created a rule for free shipping above Rs. 300

Comment: its not getting applied

Comment: is it possible to share admin details or create a new user for me for a moment so that i can check the rule

Comment: it is getting applied only if we clear the browser caches eachtime. this is what the issue to be fixed

Comment: you mean i need to clear my cache remove the items and then add again then it will get applied.

Comment: no use same items but, clear your browser cache and refresh the page once again

Comment: no after clearing and all above process rule is not getting applied.if i clear a cache my acount gets log out

Comment: i think you made some mistakes in rule please check it once. as the above process is correct for the rule creation. if you are satisfied with the answer then you can accept and upvote it so that it will help others.